# All browsers applying 'body' font to 'p' (paragraphs), except Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, inheritance

This is a demo website: http://reddledemo.wordpress.com (No, this is not a WordPress-related question.)

What I noticed is that the page's content appears in 'sans-serif' font-family in all modern browsers (essentially the latest versions of Chrome, FireFox, Safari, Opera) except Internet Explorer (tested on IE9).

The 'body' tag has a defined font, which should automatically be applied to the menus and 'p' paragraphs as they inherit the style. But in the given example, this is not happening.

Looking at the CSS, I see no obvious issues, unless I'm completely missing something. So, what could it be? (This is the first time I've encountered such a bug.)

Comment: add the desired font-family to P also

Comment: @palsingh But that shouldn't be necessary. 'p' should inherit the style from 'body'.

Comment: you are using reset css, maybe that is causing, so you have to declare rules of P

Comment: @palsingh My understanding is that if the 'reset' css is causing this problem, it should also be visible in other browsers.

Comment: i am not sure about it, but one thing i am sure that never compare IE with firefox or chrome

Comment: Hey define the font-family :xx; in sapretely in your body and remove the shortcut of font-family in your body ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay this may sound stupid but the thing is, Internet Explorer 9, which happens to be the only browser to support `rem` aka `root em` font-size value in its family (older versions of IE), does not support the `font` CSS property **when using `rem`**.

Hence,

```
font: 1.3rem Verdana, sans-serif;
```

Should be presented as this (below) in your stylesheet:

```
font-size: 1.3rem;
font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
```

It goes without saying that `rem` is supported only by a few modern browsers, and IE 9 is one among them (except for this bug).

**PROOF OF CONCEPT (w.r.t IE9):**

- This fiddle works fine & I'm not using `rem` : http://jsfiddle.net/SBrda/3/
- The same fiddle does not work fine when `rem` is uses instead of `em` : http://jsfiddle.net/SBrda/4/
- And when I break the `font` property into `font-size` and `font-family` properties, the above fiddle seems to render fine whilst using `rem` : http://jsfiddle.net/SBrda/5/

hope this will help :D

Comment: Yes, it's the `rem` that's tripping up previous versions of IE. However, I believe it should work in IE9.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn but I've also provided a fallback just for IE. I've used both `font: 13px Arial,sans-serif;` and `font: 1.3rem Arial,sans-serif;` . And yes, `rem` is said to work in IE9. So, the issue is probably something else, IMO. Still trying to figure it out...

Comment: @Pankaj `rem` is not a typo. It's intentional. [Read this](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem). Basically it stands for "root em"

Comment: Ya I found that :D and removed AsaP

Comment: @geekpanth3r see this : http://csswizardry.com/2011/05/font-sizing-with-rem-could-be-avoided/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10421/discussion-between-geekpanth3r-and-pankaj)

Answer (score 1):

IE 9 supports the `rem` unit in general but not in a `font` shorthand. Demo:

```
<!doctype html>
<style>
p { font: 1.35rem Courier; }
</style>
<p>Hello world
```

IE 9 ignores the entire rule, using its default font size and default font family. So there is apparently a bug in its parsing routines, causing it to treat `rem` as unrecognized here, hence discarding the rule.

It works if you split the shorthand CSS rule into two rules:

```
p { font-size: 1.35rem; font-family: Courier; }
```

Comment: Pankaj's answer above has confirmed this. Thanks for the answer though. :)

Comment: The only bug is, that IE can't automatically find a value from which to calculate `rem`. My answer works fine in IE, if you just declare `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: @Teemu you can show a working fiddle that would be easy to prove :)